# setting variables using logcial OR

Tags: php, logical-operators

```
$db_hased_pw = $result["password"] || false;
```

I understand the usage of this line of code, but WHEN will it evaluate as false?

will `$db_hased_pw` equal false only when `$result["password"]` is undefined?

or is `$db_hased_password` be set to false if `$result["password"]` is unset, or false, or zero, or null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will evaluate to false when `$result["password"]` is a "falsy value". The page on [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) describes these values.

These would be equivalent:

```
$db_hased_pw = !!$result["password"];
$db_hased_pw = (bool) $result["password"];
```

If `$result["password"]` can indeed be undefined, you should be using:

```
$db_hased_pw = !empty($result["password"]);
```

to avoid a notice.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP documentation:

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

You can read more on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) page.